# C++ ReadFile() from pipe fails when ASLR is disabled?

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, readfile, aslr

I wanted to demonsrate a stack overflow exploit. For this purpose i wrote this buggy Code. I know that ReadFile generates a overflow by reading 1024 bytes in the 500 bytes buffer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{
    HANDLE ReadHandle;
    char buffer[500];
    DWORD read;


    ReadHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    ReadFile(ReadHandle, buffer, 1024, &read, NULL);

    std::cout << "Der eingegebene Text war:\n";
    std::cout << buffer;

    return 0;
}
```

Then I can pipe in the shellcode like this in the cmd:

```
echo helloworld | bufferoverflow_piped
```

But the Problem is, that i want to run a shellcode with it, and for simplicity, I disabled ASLR (Switch /DYNAMICBASE:NO), but when i do it, ReadFile creates an Error. When you look at the Errorcode via the getLastError(), the code is 998, which is ERROR_NOACCESS

When I enable ASLR, it works perfectly fine. This does not make any sense to me. I mean, it shouldn't make any difference if the programm is compiled with or without ASLR. The only thing I thought is the cause were security reasons, but i don't really think so.

I hope i'm not overseeing something here

Comment: kernel check buffer for write access. if check fail - `ERROR_NOACCESS` returned. so and must be so.

Comment: Ok, but why does it work when ASLR is enabled?

Comment: because can be another memory layout. what is after your stack ? undefined. in all case `NtReadFile` check your buffer. all it size must be valid and writable. call alloca(1024) at begin of your function (main)

Comment: however in this case you overwrite only bytes allocated by alloca.. call `ReadFile` from subroutine and in caller function allocate enough stack space

Comment: ok thanks now i got it

Comment: @JeromeTrachsel If the issue solved you can post answer and accept it.